# How to remove product attribute row woocommerce using code

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, customization

I am trying to remove an attribute row in a product attribute tab using code.

Woocommerce uses javascript to hide attribute row then uses ajax to save changes.

I need this row to be disappeared and removed after product page was refreshed.

Is there a function or a method to help me remove this row?

[image: sample]

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution after some digging in database:

```
$product_attributes = get_post_meta( $product->id , '_product_attributes' );

                $temp_product_attributes = [];
                foreach($product_attributes as $product_attribute) {
                    foreach($product_attribute as $pt_k => $pt_v) {
                        if ($pt_k !== $attribute_name) {
                            $temp_product_attributes[$pt_k] = $pt_v;
                        }
                    }
                }
update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_product_attributes', $temp_product_attributes);
```

First we need to get all of `product attributes` then we traverse the array and remove the attribute we don't want any more (by the way I have store unwanted attribute in `$attribute_name`).

At the end we save the post meta with new product attributes without the one we wanted to eliminate.

`$temp_product_attributes` is for saving the attributes we already have.